# Contour Plot Gradient Vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Can someone please help me solve the question? I do not understand how to calculate the $\mathrm{d}s$ in the denominator. The question does say a unit distance is given but I do not understand what it implies.

> **2D-9** The accompanying picture shows the level curves of a function $w=f(x,y)$. The value of $w$ on each curve is marked. A unit distance is given.
> a) Draw in the gradient vector at $A$.
> b) Find a point $B$ where $w = 3$ and $\partial w/\partial x = 0$.
> c) Find a point $C$ where $w = 3$ and $\partial w/\partial y = 0$.
> d) At the point $P$ estimate the value of $\partial w/\partial x$ and $\partial w /\partial y$.
> e) At the point $Q$. estimate $dw/ds$ in the direction of $\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j}$
> f) At the point $Q$, estimate $dw/ds$ in the direction of $\mathbf{i} - \mathbf{j}$.
> g) Approximately where is the gradient $0$?
> [image: 2]

Comment: $dw/ds$ seems to be the [Directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative). You don't calculate $ds$, you calculate $(\nabla w)\cdot \frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is given.

Comment: but how do I calculate $∇$$w$ from the plot

Comment: The problem here for me is...I'm unable to understand the contour plot